# Json value in Null hot to catch Javascript exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get data json throw ajax from action-struts 2 for my view. some data set of data.

Example

```
{"home":"1234","room": null}.
```

I can read `data.home`, and I get 1234 value, but when I try read `data.room`, I got Uncaught error in console of browser, How can I do to manage this Uncaught error...

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: I try to read json null value. var t = data.room, and get exception in console browser.

Comment: I would suggest you post more details about your code, simply access data.room won't throw any exception unless you try to access something under data.room like data.room.propOrFunc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add a test

```js
/* ------
var
  data = {"home":"1234","room": null},
  h    = (data.home) ? data.home : '',
  r    = (data.room) ? data.room : 0;
------ */
var
  data = {"home":"1234","room": null},
  h    = data.home || '',
  r    = data.room || 0;
  
console.log('h=',h);
console.log('r=',r);
```

Comment: Excelent just I'm need.

Answer (score 1):

In this way you can deal with null values in your object ,you can replace them with empty string or whatever values you want you wont face exception in this way in browser.See [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
let obj={"home":"1234","room": null};
let newobj=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj),(key,value)=> value===null? "" : value )    
console.log(newobj)
```

Comment: Thank, I'll need too

Answer (score 0):

Try to sanitise you data before trying to access the values, like this:

```js
...some ajax resulting in 'data'
// replace null's for empty strings ""
JSON.stringify(data).replace(/null/i, "\"\"");
```

This way you will get an empty string instead of null (if this is what you want to)

Comment: Use this way if you always receive the same result model. If you try to find a property that does not exist in the 'data' result, you will still get an exception.